# Export To Excel - Issue with "&" in a QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have three query strings (querystring1=100, querystring2=A&B, querystring3=300) and the URL is showing as `http://mywebsite.com?querystring1=100&querystring2=A%26B&querystring3=300`.  (The querystring2 "A&B" is encoded as "A%26B").  It is returning the data correctly and no issues so far.  However, my ExportToExcel method which has

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('" & Request.Url.ToString & "&excel=true&PageSize=" & TotalRecs.ToString() & "','_new', '');
history.go(-1);
</script>")
```

is not working correctly because the querystring2 in URL is decoded to "A&B" when the page is rendered i.e.  `http://mywebsite.com?querystring1=100&querystring2=A&B&querystring3=300&excel=true&PageSize=3`. It is taking querystring value as "A" instead of "A&B". Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Server.UrlEncode`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: How can I use Server.UlrEncode here: `Response.Write("<script>window.open('" & Request.Url.ToString & "&excel=true&PageSize=" & TotalRecs.ToString() & "','_new', '');history.go(-1);</script>")`

Comment: Append `Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString())` not the un-encoded string.

Comment: So, you have the url that is not being encoded, so it puts & instad of %26. Also, & is a special char in the urls, so later that url is being misinterpreted. `Response.Write("<script>window.open('" & Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString) & "&excel=true&PageSize=" & TotalRecs.ToString() & "','_new', '');history.go(-1);</script>")`

Comment: Right! I think you just need to remove the urlencode and use Request.Url.Raw. If it doesn't work, just check the properties of the Url object, there's someone for you

Comment: If not, here is the URI documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: Yes, Request.RawURL did the trick!  Thank you so much and I really apprciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string querystring2="A&B";
Response.Redirect("http://mywebsite.com?querystring2"+ Server.UrlEncode(querystring2));
```

Comment: I am not calling the URL directly.  How can I use Server.UrlEnclode in the following code? `Response.Write("<script>window.open('" & Request.Url.ToString & "&excel=true&PageSize=" & TotalRecs.ToString() & "','_new', '');history.go(-1);</script>")`

Comment: just use Server.UrlEncode(TotalRecs.ToString()) instead TotalRecs.ToString()